# Getting Objects with specified values from hashtable Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

I have a hashtable with (String, Object). I have to segregate all objects by the length of the key String and create an array of arrays of Strings with the same length. Can someone guide me how could I accomplish that? 
My code so far:

```
Set<String> keys = words.keySet();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>>();
ArrayList<Word> inner = new ArrayList<Word>();  

for(String key: keys) {
    for (int i=0; i< 15; i++) {
        if (key.length() == i) {
            inner.add(words.get(key));
        }
        outer.add(i, inner);
    }
}
```

Comment: How many actual arrays are there in the final output?  Have you done any work yet on this problem?

Comment: There is one array with multiple arrays inside.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're looping is inefficient since you may not have many words of certain sizes so you'll be needlessly checking the length of every single word against `i` for each length. You can just go through your list of words once and use a map to associate words with the keys representing their lengths, then collate the lists at the end.

Try this:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> sizeMap = new HashMap<>();

for (String key: keys) {
    int length = key.length();
    if (sizeMap.containsKey(length)) {
        // If we already have a list initialized, add the word
        List<String> mWords = sizeMap.get(length);
        mWords.add(key);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, add an empty list so later we don't try appending to null
        sizeMap.put(length, new ArrayList<>());
    }
}

// Convert the map to a list of lists
for (List<String> sizeGrouping : sizeMap.values()) {
    outer.add(sizeGrouping);
}
```